# Creating a session variable for the OracleConnection handler in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, session, session-variables

I have an ASP.NET C# web application with multiple web pages, each of which accesses and Oracle database. I am using the (**OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString)**) handler to access the oracle database from c# in each of the webpages. I would like to create a single handler in the first webpage and pass it as a session variable to minimize the number of connections opened.

I created a session variable using the following command:

```
Session.Add("OracleHandler",con);
```

I tried to access the session variable in a different webpage using:

```
OracleConnection con = (OracleConnection)(Session["OracleHandler"]);
OracleCommand SqlCodeSelect = new OracleCommand(CodeSelect, con);**
```

But i get the following error message when i tried to run it:

`Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you have to worry about that as you won't be gaining very much. The .net engine handles a pool of connections and keep them opened to serve different requests.

For more details please check "Connection Pooling for OracleClient" on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot Claudio. I'm currently opening a new connection to Oracle every time i access the database. My DBA saw 76 connection requests to oracle using her Oracle UI and has asked me to cut down on the number of requests. Do you think there is anything wrong in the way i use session variables to access the handler? If we can't access handlers are there any other alternatives?

Comment: @varun kumhar: although .net engine keep a pool of connections, you sill need to call `close` as soon as you're done with the connection to release it (return it to the pool so it can serve other requests). You can show your connection usage code if you want.

Comment: Hi Claudio. Thanks for your reply. I am closing the connections. In this case, I'm referring to the total number of connection requests. I am opening a connection every time i access the database(eg. in the rowdatabound function) and close it after the access. Is there a way i can add the Oracle Connection handler to a session variable and access it in other pages? The above method that i tried didn't work out....

Comment: @varun kumhar: I'm afraid that I cannot suggest any approach for doing that because don't think it is the correct approach. If you release connections as you're supposed to do, you shouldn't need to do that. I'm sorry not to be able to be more helpful.